# ExtJs. Easyest way to show empty grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using **ExtJs 4**. I have a grid, but i don't have a store or columns pre defined. I just don't know what grid should be showing. But i still nead to render grid using Json markup.

I want to do something like this:

```
//grid with empty store and no collumns
{ 
    xtype: 'grid',
    columns: [],
    store: new ArrayStore([])
}
```

**What is the easyest way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load create a grid without any columns.. however you can create one without any data (just set store to `autoload: false`). For example..

```
{
   xtype: 'grid',
   //..other config here
   store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      url: 'store/url.php',
      autoLoad: false
   }),
   cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
     columns: [
        { dataIndex: 'id', header: '&nbsp;' }
     ]
   })
}
```